# Grunt phpcs multiple tasks don't run

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, gruntjs

I try to implement a plujgin for the WordPress, and I use the `phpcs` with the `WordPress` standarts.

In my case the problem is that the default `WordPress` standards for `phpcs` checks also for the WordPress-VIP that is out of my needs, and what I like to do, is to test my code against the `Extra`, `Docs` and `Core` standards.

So, in my app I have install the `grunt-phpcs` module and inside my `Gruntfile.js` I installed the sample code that is like the following and works fine:

```
phpcs : {
    application : {
        src : [
            'includes/**/*.php',
            'php/**/*.php',
            'my-plugin.php'
        ]
    },
    options     : {
        bin      : '/usr/local/bin/phpcs',
        standard : 'WordPress-Extra'
    }
}
```

But as I describe above, this doesn't solve my problem, so I try the following method:

```
phpcs : {
        extra : {
            application : {
                src : [
                    'includes/**/*.php',
                    'php/**/*.php',
                    'my-plugin.php'
                ]
            },
            options     : {
                bin      : '/usr/local/bin/phpcs',
                standard : 'WordPress-Extra'
            }
        },
        docs : {
            application : {
                src : [
                    'includes/**/*.php',
                    'php/**/*.php',
                    'my-plugin.php'
                ]
            },
            options     : {
                bin      : '/usr/local/bin/phpcs',
                standard : 'WordPress-Docs'
            }
        },
        core : {
            application : {
                src : [
                    'includes/**/*.php',
                    'php/**/*.php',
                    'my-plugin.php'
                ]
            },
            options     : {
                bin      : '/usr/local/bin/phpcs',
                standard : 'WordPress-Core'
            }
        }
    }
```

But this time, when I try to run the `grunt phpcs:extra` or the `grunt phpcs:docs` or the `grunt phpcs:core`, I get as a result the `phpcs --help`, meaning that the `phpcs` doesn't work this way.

So, is there any other way to perform the same tasks but this time to be work?

Another option I am thinking of, is to do something like the following:

```
grunt.registerTask('phpcs_extra', function() {
    // do stuff
}

grunt.registerTask('phpcs_docs', function() {
    // do stuff
}

grunt.registerTask('phpcs_core', function() {
    // do stuff
}
```

but I am not sure if that can work.

Comment: Note that the Extra standard already includes the Core standard, so there is no need to include it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the registerTask below:

```
grunt.registerTask('phpcs_extra', function() {

    var application = {
        src : [
            'includes/**/*.php',
            'php/**/*.php',
            'my-plugin.php'
        ]
    };

    var options = {
        bin      : '/usr/local/bin/phpcs',
        standard : 'WordPress-Extra'
    };

    grunt.config.set('phpcs.application', application);
    grunt.config.set('phpcs.options', options);
    grunt.task.run('phpcs');

});
```